# Python wait and check if file is created completely by external program

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, time, thread-safety

I currently have external program outputting in the file in directory 'DIR'. Now if I want to see from python if the file is created completely, how can I check that and if done execute program.

My research indicate that it could be done via

```
os.path.isfile(FILE_NAME)
```

but how do I keep on checking, in a way it does not mess-up other program. Here is something I had an idea about ? Please let me know how this can be achieved ? or is my template good enough ?

```
counter = 0;

While os.path.isfile(FILE_NAME) == False:
 Time.Sleep(3)
 counter += 1

if counter < 5:
   # I guess we are good at this point ?
```

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: In the script that creates the file, acquire an exclusive lock on it. In this script, try also to acquire a lock. The program will wait until the lock is acquired, at which point you know that the file has been created.

Comment: Did you write the external program? If not, can you run it (for a command-line tool that just does its thing and then quits) or script it (e.g., using COM or AppleScript for a Windows or Mac GUI app) from your script? In either of those cases, there are much better ways to do this (as Waleed Khan's comment suggests for the first case). If neither of those is true, there is _no_ way to do this reliably; depending on your platform and what you know about the program, you can come up with a better guess than you have, but it'll still be a guess.

Comment: @abarnert, thanks for your interest. It is external program that write the program, but is executed from the the python script via cmd.

Comment: @JennCole: Then can you just wait for the program to exit, instead of just waiting for it to stop writing to the file? Because it's very easy to wait for a program that you launched to exit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method apparently only works on Windows (ref. comment below), and relies on the fact that your external program only open and closes the file once during the creation of it.

```
import time

filename = 'my_file.txt'
while True:
    try:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as _:
            break
    except IOError:
        time.sleep(3)
```

If you want to set a maximum limit to the number of access attempts, you can do something like this:

```
import time

filename = 'my_file.txt'
max_i = 10

for i in xrange(max_i):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as _:
            break
    except IOError:
        time.sleep(3)
else:
    raise IOError('Could not access {} after {} attempts'.format(filename, str(max_i)))
```

Comment: This won't work (a) on any platform besides Windows, (b) with any program that opens and closes a file more than once while creating it, (c) with various kinds of file sharing even on Windows, …

Comment: @abarnert (a) I wasn't aware of this. How would you propose to achieve this in other platforms? (b) This is pretty obvious, and I'd think the OP would provided information if this is not the case. (c) Can you provide some examples?

Comment: If you control the _other_ program, the one that generates the data, there are many better solutions. If not, there really _is_ no way to be sure that someone has finished writing a file without some external signal; you can build a heuristic solution by using a fswatch tool like `inotify` or by asking the kernel for all handles to the file (e.g., via `lsof`), etc. But otherwise, if the other program isn't locking the file in any way, you can't detect when it's unlocked the file, because no such thing happens. (This sort of works on Windows because all file opens implicitly lock by default.)